# Unable to add additional file extensions in Drupal 7

Tags: image, drupal

Im using Drupal 7 to create a page that allows me to give a title, body and upload an image. The allowed file extensions for uploading an image are jpg, jpeg, gif and png. I want to add more image types as bmp, tiff and rif. To solve this I edited the image field for the content type I created for the purpose by adding more extensions to the "Allowed file extensions" in the edit field and saved but still I couldnt add bmp images. Is there a way I can add such additional extensions?

Comment: Voting for closing this question being unclear. I have no idea what technologies you are using, what you want to achieve and what you have done trying to solve it yourself. Edit the question to be more precise and tag the right technologies which you are using.

Comment: Oops Im sorry, I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my question as directed.